# Search some string in Java code and replace it

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

In this java code that some one else has written, people have used `null` check condition as `null!=abc` or `null==abc`, but I need to change it to `abc!=null` and `abc==null` respectively.

Someone told me that this can be done using regular expressions very easily, as till now I was performing a manual task, but searching it and then replacing it manually.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you have to change it?

Comment: @haward : One of managers have told me.. even i don't know why.. just i need to change..

Comment: What editor/environment/ide are you doing this in-- that's relevant for how you would do the regex

Comment: Are you sure you want to change `null==abc` to `abc=null`?  Those have two different meanings (hint hint, one is assignment)

Comment: @mrk: have updated the question.Please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know all the requirements for what could be on the right side of the boolean expression, but assuming it is a variable name, `\w` will be a **roughly** accurate search (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html for the full specification of variable names).

Search string:

```
null\s*([!=]=)\s*(\w+)
```

Replace string

```
$1 $2 null
```

Comment: You should replace `\s+` with `\s*` to match also the examples given by OP.

Comment: @Howard thank you, I think that is what I was thinking, don't know why I put `+`.

Comment: @Renesis : i tried with the above one. First the replace string should be `$2 $1 null`, and more over this works only with simple conditions, not for complex conditions. I am also reading the same, and will comment once i am able to find something.

Comment: @Renesis : do u have any idea how to do .. i tried many cases but all does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done correctly with regular expressions.

Consider

```
/*
Print whether null==abc.
*/
System.out.print("null==abc : " + (null==abc));
```

If you want to change only the code, the third `null==abc` above, then you can get unintended changes to string and comment content by naively using regular expression replaces to change code.

And you want to be careful to not change

```
null==abc.def
```

to

```
abc==null.def
```

or to change

```
null==abc(def)
```

to

```
abc==null(def)
```

If you're OK with potential string and comment changes, and are going to review the changes to make sure you didn't break any method calls, then you can always do this in perl.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/null(\s*[!=]=\s*)([\w.]+)/$2$1null/g' YourJavaFile.java
```